# How to create table of contents based on # or ## in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the text like this:

```
var text = `# Algorithms
This chapter covers the most basic algorithms.
## Sorting
Quicksort is fast and widely used in practice
Merge sort is a deterministic algorithm
## Searching
DFS and BFS are widely used graph searching algorithms
Some variants of DFS are also used in game theory applications
# Data Structures
This chapter is all about data structures
It's a draft for now and will contain more sections in the future
# Binary Search Trees`;
```

I am able to get the # strings:

```
var headers = text.match(/(#[^\n]+)/g);
console.log('headers: ',headers); 
["# Algorithms", "## Sorting", "## Searching", "# Data Structures", "# Binary Search Trees"]
```

Now the requirement is I need to create table of contents based on `#` followed by `##`

If it is single `#` and followed by double `##` then its like this:

```
1. Algorithms
1.1. Sorting
1.2. Searching
2. Data Structures
3. Binary Search Trees
```

How do I check if it is single `#` and then followed by double `##`?

Comment: there might be more than  2 #?

Comment: @Berto99 No. There would be either single or double #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working but there is probably a cleaner way to do it:

```js
let inp = ["# Algorithms", "## Sorting", "## Searching", "# Data Structures", "# Binary Search Trees"]

let curInd = [0, 0];
let out = inp.reduce( (acc, el) => {
    let n_of_hashtag = (el.match(/#/g) || []).length;
    let inp_without_hashtag = el.replace(/#*/g,'');
    if(n_of_hashtag == 1){
        acc[el] = `${++curInd[0]}.${inp_without_hashtag}`;
        curInd[1] = 1;
    } else {
        acc[el] = `${curInd[0]}.${curInd[1]++}. ${inp_without_hashtag}`;
    }
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(out);
```

Comment: @kittu what you mean? that of the resulting object you only need the values and not the keys?

Answer (score 1):

If there is either a single or double `#`, you could split on a newline, check if the string starts with either `#`  or `##`  and use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to remove the leading chars.

```
let result = [];
let countSingle = 0, countDouble = 0;

text.split('\n').forEach(s => {
    if (s.startsWith("# ")) {
        countSingle++; countDouble = 0;
        result.push(`${countSingle}.${s.substr(1,)}`);
        return;
    }
    if (s.startsWith("## ")) {
        countDouble++;
        result.push(`${countSingle}.${countDouble}.${s.substr(2,)}`);            
    }
})
```

```js
var text = `# Algorithms
This chapter covers the most basic algorithms.
## Sorting
Quicksort is fast and widely used in practice
Merge sort is a deterministic algorithm
## Searching
DFS and BFS are widely used graph searching algorithms
Some variants of DFS are also used in game theory applications
# Data Structures
This chapter is all about data structures
It's a draft for now and will contain more sections in the future
# Binary Search Trees
## test
`;

let result = [];
let countSingle = 0,
  countDouble = 0;

text.split('\n').forEach(s => {
  if (s.startsWith("# ")) {
    countSingle++;
    countDouble = 0;
    result.push(`${countSingle}.${s.substr(1,)}`);
    return;
  }
  if (s.startsWith("## ")) {
    countDouble++;
    result.push(`${countSingle}.${countDouble}.${s.substr(2,)}`);
  }
})
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```js
const makeTOC = function(text) {
  const idxs = [0, 0];
  return text.split("\n").reduce((acc, line) => {
    const m = line.match(/^(#+)\s*(.+)$/);
    if (m) {
      if (m[1].length == 1) {
        idxs[0]++;
        idxs[1] = 0;
      } else {
        idxs[1]++;
      }
      if (idxs[1]) acc.push(`${idxs[0]}.${idxs[1]}. ${m[2]}`);
      else acc.push(`${idxs[0]}. ${m[2]}`);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []).join("\n");
}

const text = `# Algorithms
This chapter covers the most basic algorithms.
## Sorting
Quicksort is fast and widely used in practice
Merge sort is a deterministic algorithm
## Searching
DFS and BFS are widely used graph searching algorithms
Some variants of DFS are also used in game theory applications
# Data Structures
This chapter is all about data structures
It's a draft for now and will contain more sections in the future
# Binary Search Trees`;

console.log( makeTOC(text) );
```

Regex explained [here](https://regex101.com/r/apXcYN/1).

Note that this solution assumes there are no more than two consecutive `#`.

Comment: The solution proposed gives an unexpected output. The headings (starting with `#`) should be preceded by a single-digit index only